# Represent in first-order-logic the following sentence

Tags: first-order-logic

I have the following sentence:

`Everyone loves dogs or hates dogs`

Note: love is not the negation of hate.

Is this the right representation?

$$\tag{1} \forall X.\forall Y. (LovesDog(X) \lor HatesDog(Y)) $$

Comment: One variable suffices.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is incorrect. For example, consider a world where there are two people, Alice and Bob, where:
$$
Alice \mapsto lovesdog \quad bob \mapsto hatesdog
$$. In this world, it is **false** that $\forall X, \forall Y, lovesdog(X) \lor hatesdog(Y)$. Consider the cases:
\begin{align*}
&X=alice, Y=bob: lovesdog(alice) \lor hatesdog(bob) &= true ~\lor~true = true \\
&X=alice, Y=alice: lovesdog(alice) \lor hatesdog(alice) &= true ~\lor~false = true \\
&X=bob, Y=bob: lovesdog(bob) \lor hatesdog(bob) &= true ~\lor~false = true \\
&X=bob, Y=alice: lovesdog(bob) \lor hatesdog(alice) &= false ~\lor~false = \mathbf{false} \\
\end{align*}

However, it is indeed true that in this world, everyone loves *or* hates dogs: alices loves dogs, and bob hates dogs.

The correct statement ought to be:

$$
\forall X, lovesdog(X) \lor hatesdog(X)
$$
because this is saying "for every person $X$, they either loves dogs or hate them.

The reason your statement is wrong is that it is saying "for every *pair* of people (X, Y), X loves dogs or Y hates dogs", which is false as we showed.

Comment: Your notation is in line 2 is very unusual. Why would one have a function from objects to single non-logical symbols? Rather, I suppose what you want to express is that $\mathcal{I} : lovesdogs \mapsto \{Alice\}, hatesdogs \mapsto \{Bob\}$, where $\mathcal{I}$ is the structure's interpretation function.